# Listview item index visible to the user

Tags: android, listviewitem

Really really need some help with this!!!

I have a list view, where user can add data (rows) to it. Also can delete rows (context menu per listviewitem)
For each listviewitem there is a textbox with the row number in it. The number is incremented for each row, if rows are being deleted then rows number are changed as well (all rows below the deleted item index are decremented by 1)

I have the following code which needs to be updated (for memory leak, already know how to do it). The question is regarding the row index that is shown to the user. I think my way to do it is WRONG.
If there is a way to do it with the stableids? with the row index? 
I guess there is but could not find examples for it on the WEB.

I have understood that getting the row number according to the possition is wrong, although this one works

Basicly what I need is to inflate the related layout according to the position (first or last)

Here is the getView function

```
@Override
public View getView(    int         position, 
                        View        convertView, 
                        ViewGroup   parent ) 
{
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    if( convertView == null )
    {
        if( position == 0 && position == getCount() - 1 )
        {
            // TODO
            convertView             = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_ingredient_list_up_view_entry, null);//mSingleItem; 
            viewHolder.mTextView    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeIngredientNameTextBoxId );;//mSingleTextView;
        }
        else if( position == 0)
        {
            convertView             = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_ingredient_list_up_view_entry, null);//mUpItem;
            viewHolder.mTextView    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeIngredientNameTextBoxId );;//mUpTextView;
        }
        else if( position == getCount() - 1 )
        {
            convertView             = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_ingredient_list_down_view_entry, null);;;;//mDownItem;
            viewHolder.mTextView    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listDown_RecipeIngredientNameTextBoxId );;;//mDownTextView;
        }
        else
        {
            convertView             = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_ingredient_list_middle_view_entry, null);//mMiddleItem;
            viewHolder.mTextView    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listMiddle_RecipeIngredientNameTextBoxId );;// mMiddleTextView;
        }

        viewHolder.mTextView.setTypeface( GlobalData.Fonts.ARIAL );
        viewHolder.mTextView.setTextSize(14);
        viewHolder.mTextView.setTextColor( Color.BLACK );
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if( super.getItem(position) != null )
    {
        viewHolder.mTextView.setText( mItems.get(position) );
        convertView.setTag( viewHolder );
    } 

    return convertView;
}
```